# AsyncImage cannot fetch image

Tags: python, image, kivy

I am trying to use a Kivy [AsyncImage](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#asynchronous-loading) as follows:

```
import kivy
from kivy.loader import Loader
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return AsyncImage(source="https://colruyt.collectandgo.be/cogo/step/JPG/JPG/500x500/std.lang.all/64/86/asset-366486.jpg")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

But I get the error:

```
[ERROR  ] [Loader      ] Failed to load image <https://colruyt.collectandgo.be/cogo/step/JPG/JPG/500x500/std.lang.all/64/86/asset-366486.jpg>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/loader.py", line 342, in _load_urllib
    data = self._load_local(_out_filename, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/loader.py", line 277, in _load_local
    return ImageLoader.load(filename, keep_data=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 432, in load
    raise Exception('Unknown <%s> type, no loader found.' % ext)
Exception: Unknown <html> type, no loader found.
an integer is required
```

The same happens if I run this on my Mac or on my Raspberry Pi. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

It seems to be an http header problem. The url is returning an html error page because the http headers are not correct:

`<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 2461894905373175944</body></html>`

I can not figure out how to set custom headers for a AsyncImage in Kivy. Any suggestions?